# Was mathematics created by some being?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

Was mathematics created by some being, like maybe God? I believe that mathematics is timeless and uncreated, but have any academic philosophers proposed that math was created by some being? By "mathematics", I don't mean the human discipline of doing mathematics, I mean the collection of mathematical objects and truths themselves.

Comment: There is a sense in which mathematics is timeless and "uncreated", and there is a sense in which it is created by mathematicians. And yes, it is the collection of mathematical objects and truths that is created by them, not just the "human discipline". Before Peano and others gave a definition of vector space neither they nor truths about them existed (in one sense), or, if we platonically backproject everything mathematical as "existing" (in another sense), then they always did. But in both senses of "create" and "exist" the answer to the title question is trivial, yes and no, respectively.

Comment: Ok, I have to confess: it was me.

Comment: Yes mathematics was created by some being. Human beings who had never read Euclid because there was no Euclid yet. Basically it was created as humans struggled to survive in the world.